# Select2 is slow on opening with 10.000+ elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm using Select2 to fill Dropdowns. *Select2* is slow when opening its dropdown menu if the underlying select has a fair number of items. I have more than 10.000+ elements in my dropdown.

Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Companies/GetCompanies",
    method: "get",
    success: function (data) {
        if (data != null) {
            var newWorkPlaceId = $("#newWorkPlaceId");
            newWorkPlaceId.empty();
            newWorkPlaceId.append("<option value=''> -- Choose-- </option>");

            $.each(data, function (index, item) {

                newWorkPlaceId.append(
                 $('<option>', {
                     value: item.id,
                     text: item.text
                 }, '</option>'));
            });
        $("#newWorkPlaceId").select2({
            placeholder: {
                id: "",
                placeholder: " -- Choose--"
            },
            allowClear: true
        });


        }
        clearconsole();
    }
});
```

Is there a way to make the *Select2* widget (or another searchable *dropdown*) respond faster?

Note: I am using ASP.NET CORE

Comment: It's never a good idea to have 10k+ options in a select element: that's going to be bad UX experience, because of (1) the number of choices the user has to scroll through and (2) the 10k+ DOM nodes rendering slowing down the browser. What you should consider is a typeahead solution, i.e. suggest options as the user types. In that way, you are always only displaying a limited subset of possible options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After long research I found that 2 symbols limitation will help me to fix this. Here is my solution

```
$("#newWorkPlaceId").select2({

    allowClear: true,
    placeholder: {
        id: "",
        placeholder: "Choose."
    },
    language: {
        inputTooShort: function (args) {

            return "2 or more symbol.";
        },
        noResults: function () {
            return "Not Found.";
        },
        searching: function () {
            return "Searching...";
        }
    },
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    ajax: {
        url: 'url',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "GET",
        quietMillis: 50,
        data: function(term) {
            return {
                term: term.term
            };
        },
        processResults: function (response) {
            return {
                results: response
            };
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to use AJAX data and pagination like below

```
$('#mySelect2').select2({
  ajax: {
    url: 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories',
    data: function (params) {
      var query = {
        search: params.term,
        page: params.page || 1
      }

      // Query parameters will be ?search=[term]&page=[page]
      return query;
    }
  }
});
```

---

***Example***

```js
$('#mySelect2').select2({
  ajax: {
    url: function (params) {
      return 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q='+params.term+'&page='+params.page || 1;
    },
     processResults: function (data) {
        return {
            results: $.map(data.items, function (item) {
                return {
                    text: item.name,
                    id: item.id
                }
            })
        };
    }}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select style="width:50%" id="mySelect2"></select>
```